# Cypress not able to load a different domain used in the second test

Tags: cypress

Cypress not able to load a different domain used in the second test . I have 2 tests. In one test the user goes to https://www.google.com and login and in the second test case it goes to https://www.yahoo.com and tries to the same.I have gone through cypress documentation that's why my 2 different domains are part of 2 separate tests.But fails to load the second url in the second test.Dashboard get stuck and 2nd url not loading.How to solve this issue?

Comment: Logging via a UI to external services is not a good idea anyway. You should focus on testing your application.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress can load a different domains in different tests, but Yahoo throws some internal errors which causes Cypress to fail loading that page.

If you substitute http://www.example.com/, both domains will load.

You can suppress the Yahoo errors with [Uncaught Exceptions event](https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Uncaught-Exceptions)

At the top of the spec,

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```